# How can I required the first time user to fill up the form in php

Tags: php, forms, authentication

I want to create a system where after the user have the username and password gave by the admin, he/she will be redirected to a form where he/she needs to fill up Ex. Personal information (one- time) before proceeding to the main page or home. The next log in wouldn't have a form again.

Comment: check session, if not logged in, force registration if attempt to access account like information. The premise behind every login / registration system.

Comment: No he/she already have the login details (username &password) what i want to do is , give the user a form which he/she needs to fill up to be able to enter the system.

Answer (score -1):

There are two ways:

- First way to save a flag on users table in DB to check
- Second way to save in localStorage flag if he put this information or not.